# unix command 'mv' failure

Tags: file-io, unix, mv

I am using move command `mv -f $file1 $file2` to move a file from source directory to a destination directory. I am getting a failure message as:

```
mv: cannot create regular file $file2:File exists
```

Could you let me know on the reason for such failures from move command?

Are there any ways to solve this error?

Comment: Guess what, the error message tells you what is wrong.

Comment: fdomig: Normally, when moving files, `mv` automatically overwrites the destination, even without `-f`.

Comment: Are you running the command in a script? If so, show some more code please.

Comment: yes, you are right but I am not sure on the reasons for the above message.

Comment: I am running 'mv -f /var/tmp/test_file.txt /data/test_file.txt' command in my script.

Comment: Regarding OS: I m using Linux

Comment: @user1360733 Are you specifying the parameters directly or through variables? If using variables, show more code.

Comment: @user1360733: Could you look at the chmod and owner of both source and destination file? If possible, give some commands for completely reproducing the situation, e.g., `touch /data/filea; chmod 700 /data/filea; touch /var/tmp/fileb; chmod 700 /var/tmp/fileb; mv /var/tmp/fileb /data/filea`

Comment: Are you using a case-insensitive or case-preserving filesystem, perhaps?

Comment: @fdomig I also had this issue recursively writing a directory to an empty location. There is no way the file already exists. The question is probably due to confusion over why the error occurs when the destination clearly doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by race condition. Your were running multiple `mv` in your scripts.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463262/race-condition-while-moving-files-on-linux for details.

Answer (score 0):

Does that file really exist? If it exists, and you are **SURE** that you want to overwrite it, add the -f flag, which will force the command to continue;

```
mv -f file1 file2
```

Comment: sorry! I missed to add '-f' in the question. I am actually using '-f' in my mv command.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `-f` here; `-f` means "do not prompt before overwriting".  He's not being prompted, so this won't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by a privileges conflict and occasionally by using illegal characters in the file name. Make sure there are no unusual special characters in the file's name and verify that there is not already a file with the same name in the directory that the file is being moved to. You might need to use `ls -l` from above target directory to see if the privileges settings will allow you to read/write to the directory.